# Excel Assign a value to a column if that row is flagged

Tags: excel, csv

I have the following csv file:

```
name, new_name, flag
a,,0
b,,1
c,c,0
d,,1
```

I want to make the value in the "new_name" column become the value of the "name" column in rows where the "flag" row has a value of 1. Do I have to use an application program to do this? or is there a way of putting this equation into the "flag" column and then pasting the formula in every row in that column?

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want to happen if it's not flagged, keep `new_name`'s value? If you already have data in `new_name` you can't exactly overwrite it with a formula, but can you live with a four-column setup?

Comment: If "flag" has a 0 then I don't want anything to happen.

Comment: 4 column setup is fine, although there shouldn't be any overwriting since there is only a value in "new_name" if "flag" does not equal 1.

Comment: the key is that i want "new_name" where it already had a value to be in the same column as where the desired value will be when "flag" has a value of 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can live with a four-column setup:

```
name   | new_name  | flag  | real_new_name
a                     0            
b                     1           b
c            c        0           c
d                     1           d
```

then you can set `real_new_name` to the formula `=IF(C2=1,A2,B2)` and fill it down.

Otherwise, you will need to write a script that goes through each row and acts if flag=1.

Comment: @user1590499 Sure. Formulas are your friend :)